# Me podrían ayudar a formular estas consultas con eloquent?

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

Traer n registros

```
Modelo::where('llave', '>', $var)->take($n)->get();
```

falla porque no sabe que registros traer le falta

```
latest()

Modelo::all()->take($n);
```

esta consulta le pasa lo mismo que a la de arriba le falta el argumento lastest

Registros que se encuentren entre a y b

```
Modelo::whereIn('campo',[$a,$b])->take($n)->get();
```

Esta consulta deberia traer los campos que estén entre a y b pero solo trae los que coinciden con a y b

Las consultas aun que ya están predefinidas los parámetros son variables para mi API. Solo que cuando intento ejecutar estas consultas falla.

Comment: cuéntanos por favor que es lo que falla con las consultas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mencionas que en ambos casos debes incluir el método `latest()` por lo cual yo rearía tu consulta de este modo:

**primer consulta**

```
Modelo::where('llave', '>', $var)
       ->latest('llave')
       ->take($n)
       ->get();
```

**segunda consulta**

Para el caso de la segunda consulta, no puedes usar `take()` al mismo tiempo con el método `all()` por lo cual te sugiero hagas uso del método `select()` para indicar que columnas quieres que te traiga; si quieres todas las columnas puedes hacerlo de este modo

```
Modelo::select('*')->latest('campo')->take($n)->get();
```

**tercer consulta**

```
Modelo::whereBetween('campo',[$a,$b])
      ->latest('campo')
      ->take($n)
      ->get();
```

Le pasas al método `latest` como argumento; el nombre de la columna por la cual quieres que te haga el ordenamiento `DESC` y ya te debería devolver los resultados

> Para el caso de las 3 consultas, en el método `latest()` debes pasarle
>   entre comillas el nombre de la columna por la cual quieres hacer el
>   ordenamiento `DESC`